# Spring Integration - Use filename with gateway

Tags: spring, spring-integration, gateway

I have a problem with spring integration.

I want to make a request on an ftp server to retrieve the name of a file
(at the command line: ls "filename")

But I cannot recover the file name dynamically.
I understood that there was a story with payload or header but I can not

This is what I have:

Review  my controller, I use this :

```
private FtpConfig.MyGateway gateway;
...
gateway.fichierExist(filename);
```

in my FTP file :

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory<FTPFile> ftpSessionFactory() {
    DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
    sf.setHost("");
    sf.setPort(21);
    sf.setUsername("");
    sf.setPassword("");
    return new CachingSessionFactory<FTPFile>(sf);
}


@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "ftpChannelExist")
public MessageHandler handler2() {
    FtpOutboundGateway ftpOutboundGateway =
            new FtpOutboundGateway(ftpSessionFactory(), "ls");
    ftpOutboundGateway.setOptions("-a -1")
    FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter filter = new FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter("filename"); //on filtre sur le nom

    return ftpOutboundGateway;
}


@MessagingGateway
public interface MyGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "ftpChannelExist")
    ArrayList<String> fichierExist(String filename);

}
```

I tried with header too, but I can not do anything ...

Thanks.

(Sorry for my english, i'm french)

Answer (score 0):

See `LS` command description in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-outbound-gateway):

> In addition, filename filtering is provided, in the same manner as the `inbound-channel-adapter`.
>
> The message payload resulting from an ls operation is a list of file names, or a list of `FileInfo` objects. These objects provide information such as modified time, permissions etc.

The remote directory that the ls command acted on is provided in the `file_remoteDirectory` header.

What you are missing in your configuration is a fact of the `remote directory` to fetch files from. Typically we suggest to have such a directory in the `payload` as you do with your `fichierExist(String filename)` and configure the third ctor arg for the `FtpOutboundGateway`:

```
FtpOutboundGateway ftpOutboundGateway =
        new FtpOutboundGateway(ftpSessionFactory(), "ls", "payload");
```

According the logic in the `FtpOutboundGateway` that expression is serving as a source for the remote directory in the `LS` command. In your case this one is going to be an argument of your  `fichierExist(String filename)` gateway.

You indeed can use there a `FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter`, but be sure to specify a proper pattern to filter remote files.

In the end the names of the remote files in the requested directory, after filtering are going to be returned to the `ArrayList<String>` of your gateway. That's correct.

Otherwise your question isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply.

I have change my FtpOutboundGateway for add "payload" but I can't use payload for my FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter.

I've try :

```
FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter filter = new FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter("filename"); 

FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter filter = new FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter("payload"); 

FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter filter = new FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter("payload.filename"); 

FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter filter = new FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter("payload['filename']");
```